# How to add a script to a shared toolbox

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, python-toolbox

I have the following problem: I have a script * .py and I added it to a toolset. When using another computer and add my toolbox, it appears as an "invalid tool"
[image]

and when I enter it to "edit" it, the script appears with the X.

[image: Script1]

The idea is that this does not happen since the tool will be used by people without experience in GIS (the user of the toolbox should not enter to "edit" the toolbox). The script is inside another toolset in the same toolbox.

[image]

How should the toolbox be "packed" so that this does not happen when sharing it?

Comment: Depending on your version you should look into geoprocessing packages or toolshares.

Comment: Adding a script tool to a standard toolbox does not embed the script, it's still at the file location as a .py file, however you can put your scripts in a subfolder of the folder the toolbox is in and checking the *use relative paths*, then when you copy the toolbox to a new workstation copy all the subfolders as well. Alternately you can reference the path with UNC file names (eg \\computer\share\path\script.py) so that the script can be located *absolutely* in your network; this doesn't help if you're working on computers that aren't attached to a network.

Answer (score 2):

You should import script.

1. Right click to the script.
2. click "Import Script".

[image]

**Note:** You can set password for  scripts.

After Importing script:

1. Right click to the script => click copy.
2. Paste it to another toolbox or toolset.

Comment: hi wetland, I do that, but the tool continues with the "X", being it should "call" the script that is inside the toolset (which is inside the toolbox) ... how can I set the location of the script inside the toolbox ? I do not want to enter to edit the tool every time I change the computer. thanx!

Comment: @Ana after importing script. right click to the script => copy then paste it in the toolbox or toolset.

Answer (score 2):

Store your script in the same directory or a subset directory of your toolbox. Something like this:

[image]

Right-click on the script in your toolbox and select Properties...

[image]

Under the **General** tab click the box for **Store relative path names (instead of absolute paths)**

[image]

Now you can move the toolbar folder to different machines while maintaining the script association.